# What is meaning of $FFT(\vec{E}(x,y ))$

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab, vector-analysis

What is the meaning and how one takes fourier transformation of vector that has spatial distrubution.

Let say electric field (with transfer x, y distibution) with direction

$$FFT(\vec{E}(x,y ))$$

In matlab fft2(E(x,y)) would be fine for scalar. But how one would take FFT if it is a vector.

My question comes from fft beam propagation equation shown bellow. It is for homework and I do not have time, just $\vec{E}(x,y )$ . I do not understand how FFT is taken of a vector.

(e, p are 1x3 vectors and kz is z directed wave number 1x3 vector. The sum is over two polararizations.)

[image]

Comment: $FFT$ usually denotes the fast fourrier transform (an algorithm for computing the discrete fourrier transform of a "vector") http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform

Comment: What you want is just the vector whose components are the FFTs of the components of E.  So take the FFT of each component separately.